# Given these tables how would I select all cases that are not tagged?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

A user can have an unlimited number of cases and a case can have zero or more tags. How would I SELECT all of a specified user's cases which are **not** tagged? I'm using MySQL.

```
cases:
  id        INT
  owner_id  INT
  title     TEXT

tags:
 id         INT
 owner_id   INT
 name       TEXT

case_tag (the pivot table):
  id        INT
  case_id   INT
  tag_id    INT

users:
  id        INT
  username  VARCHAR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN cases b
            ON a.id = c.owner_id
        LEFT JOIN case_tag c
            ON b.id = c.case_id
WHERE   c.case_id IS NULL
```

What the query does is it basically select all cases of all users which has no matching record on table `case_tag`.

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

An alternative of using `LEFT JOIN` is `NOT EXISTS`,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN cases b
            ON a.id = c.owner_id
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  NULL
            FROM    case_tag c
            WHERE   b.id = c.case_id
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT u.*, c.*
FROM users u JOIN cases c ON u.id=c.owner_id LEFT JOIN case_tags ct ON c.id=ct.case_id
WHERE ct.id IS NULL
```